# Is there any method to find K value in KNN?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am new to Matlab. For me the task is to perform data classification on some data set. The given data set consists of numeric values. One thing that bothers me is I have to perform all KNN, ANN, and SVM. In performing KNN, I faced a problem of how to find the value of `K`. If it is user defined? From which value we have to start and when to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically too large `k` may tend to underfit, while smaller `k` may tend to overfit. You may try to run the classification with different `k` within the preset range with [cross-validation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_knn_training_crossvalidation.htm). Observe and find out the `k` that gives you the least cross validation sum-of-square error.

Another possible metric besides the sum-of-square error is called [Silhouette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_%28clustering%29) applied to interpretation and validation of clusters of data. The technique provides a succinct graphical representation of how well each object lies within its cluster.

Comment: Hello Lenon...Can you help em some more further ? Can you let me know briefly about Cross Validation and how to calculate it  for 2d Data set ?. I have seen about CV in web but those formula and notations makes me confused. So, please let me know when to apply CV and how to apply ?

Comment: You split your data into training set and testing set, use training set to train the model, then use the model to test how well the testing set can be classified. Just count the number of mis-classifications, the lower the better.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: Thank you lennon. I have some more questions,but, I will google them . Even I am not aware of model clearly. I mean , " what the model means " ? . I will google it. Thnk you

Comment: model is your knn result with training data as the input. Thanks

Comment: I got you. Is CV mandatory to perform in order to know best K value. Is there any other process to find it?

Comment: Since there is no theoretical k value derivation, and it is highly dependent on your problem, the grid search in CV seems to be one of the very few feasible methods. In fact CV is used in every part in machine learning to verify the model.

Comment: Lennon. I tried to know about Cross Validation but I am not succeeded .Can you please help me to know about it ?. Sorry If I bother you.